# Parameterise filtering of element in of shapeless Hlist of Lists

Tags: scala, shapeless

Simplified Use Case

```
sealed trait T1
case object Foo extends T1
case object Bar extends T1

sealed trait T2
case object Bip extends T2
case object Bop extends T2

case class Partitioner(v1: T1, v2: T2)

trait WithPartition { self =>
  def pt: Partitioner

  def byT1(t1: T1): Boolean = self.pt.v1 == t1

  def byT2(t2: T2): Boolean = self.pt.v2 == t2
}

case class PSetOne(pt: Partitioner, extraOne: Int) extends WithPartition

case class PSetTwo(pt: Partitioner, extraTwo: Int) extends WithPartition

// create lists

val ls1 = for {
  p1 <- List(Foo,Bar)
  p2 <- List(Bip,Bop)
  n <- 1 to 10
} yield PSetOne(Partitioner(p1,p2),n)

val ls2 = for {
  p1 <- List(Foo,Bar)
  p2 <- List(Bip,Bop)
  n <- 1 to 10
} yield PSetTwo(Partitioner(p1,p2),n)

// So I can filter on the list 

ls2.filter{x => x.byT1(Foo)}

// ls1 ++ ls2 => List[Product with Serializable with WithPartition] 
// but prefer to retain type using HList

val hAll = ls1 :: ls2 :: HNil

//  I can filter if I explicity supply the case object 
object parFoo extends Poly1 {
  implicit def casePset1 = at[List[PSetOne]](_.filter{x => x.byT1(Foo)})
  implicit def casePset2 = at[List[PSetTwo]](_.filter{x => x.byT1(Foo)})
}

hAll.map(parFoo)
```

What I would like to be able to do is pass the Partition value as a parameter to be able to
do something like

```
hAll.map(parT1(Foo))
```

How might I specify object parT1 such that it can use a T1 object as a parameter to the filter asin the vanilla list example above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically parametrize Poly1 function in shapeless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288806/dynamically-parametrize-poly1-function-in-shapeless)

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the duplicate reference but the technique was beyond me to understand and apply in the above situation. I have found an alternative non shapeless based solution which is to emend the code with some additional type information.

```
trait PSet

type PSP = PSet with WithPartition

case class PSetOne(pt: Partitioner, extraOne: Int) extends PSet with WithPartition

case class PSetTwo(pt: Partitioner, extraTwo: Int) extends PSet with WithPartition

// create lists with type ascription

val ls1 = for {
  p1 <- List(Foo,Bar)
  p2 <- List(Bip,Bop)
  n <- 1 to 10
} yield PSetOne(Partitioner(p1,p2),n) : PSP

val ls2 = for {
  p1 <- List(Foo,Bar)
  p2 <- List(Bip,Bop)
  n <- 1 to 10
} yield PSetTwo(Partitioner(p1,p2),n) : PSP

val als = ls1 ++ ls2 
// now gives me List[PSP] and I can

val foos = als.filter{x => x.byT1(Foo)}
val bips = als.filter{x => x.byT2(Bip)} 

// and still extract by case class

val foos1 = foos.collect{case f: PSetOne => f}
```

I am not altogether satisfied with this (though I do get to use a type alias of PSP :)) but it will do as I need for now.

If anyone can post a shapeless based solution I would be grateful, not least to help me improve my understanding.